# System of Differential equations in Python

Tags: python, differential-equations

I saw such an example and it worked:

```
g1, g2 = symbols('g1 g2', cls=Function)
eq1 = g1(x).diff(x) - 2*g1(x) - g2(x)
eq2 = g2(x).diff(x) - 3*g1(x) - 4*g2(x)
dsolve((eq1, eq2), fun=(g1(x), g2(x)))
```

Then I tried to solve this system but It says "list index out of range"

```
beta,t, m, lmbda, k,j, g,p= symbols("beta t m lambda k j g p")
p = Function("p")
F=Function("F")
U=Function("U")

def1=p(x)-1/6+3*U(x)-F(x)
def2=F(x).diff(x)-3/4*(p(x)-F(x))
def3=U(x).diff(x)+1/2*(m-p(x))

dsolve((def1, def2, def3), funcs=(p(x),F(x),U(x)))
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: What is the syntax here? Is it sympy?

Comment: Yes, it is sympy but I didn't understand what do you mean by syntax. My question is actually how Can I solve 3 or more systems of dif equations such that? I saw also "odeint" is used. but I didn't get it also.

Comment: I was asking because you didn't mention "simpy" anywhere and you shouldn't expect us to be able to figure that out...

Comment: I am sorry, I started to learn it 2 weeks ago. I am still trying to understand.

Comment: `def1` is not a differential equation. I'm not sure if `dsolve` also tackles differential-algebraic systems.

Comment: Yes, I know but it is taken from a textbook so I guess I need to check it again Thanks.